# R: Using regex within a data frame returns a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to remove the 1's from the database below:

```
                      offence offence_result gender
42         threateningBehaviour              1 female
43                      treason              1 female
44                     wounding             28 female
45                 animalTheft1           3194   male
46                       arson1             60   male
47                     assault1             55   male
48            assaultWithIntent             11   male
49 assaultWithSodomiticalIntent             27   male
```

However when I type in my code:

```
Combine_Offence2 <- str_replace(Combine_Offence$offence, "1","")
```

It simply prints these results as a new vector (rather than alter the data frame which is what I would like).

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Combine_Offence$offence <- str_replace(Combine_Offence$offence, "1","")
```